# Is there a platform to do alpha testing of apps other than google?

Tags: google-play

My intention is to do alpha testing of an app within a closed group, But google play is not allowing me to do so unless, I upload logos, screenshots etc for the app. This app is a pilot app and I dont intend to launch in market. Hence I wish to know how can I do alpha testing of an app within a closed group.

Comment: The user have to check Install Apps from Unknown Sources for any other place. So you can simply send the apk directly because there are not many other benefits from markets

Comment: but e.g. crashlytics provides an distribution where you can see who tested and if there are any errors, if you are not using something like that at the moment